# Unity xcode build fails, because of UnityFramework library not loaded?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build my Unity game with xcode for IOS. The build finishes without errors, but the game crashes while starting. (Android works) . I had this issue with unity 2019.3.7 and created a new project and imported all my stuff to 2019.4.2f but the error stayed the same:

> Error loading /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E7F144F0-19F0-4CDD-8739- 46E4E53886D4/io.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework:  dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E7F144F0-19F0-4CDD-8739-46E4E53886D4/io.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 265): Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
> Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E7F144F0-19F0-4CDD-8739-46E4E53886D4/io.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
> Reason: image not found

I changed nothing in the xcode project (build by unity). I am using Xcode 11.4 in macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (virtualbox).

I would appreciate some help.

Jonas

Comment: Why don’t you build the app from Unity?

Comment: What dou you mean with that? I click on "build" in Unity and this creates a xcode project and than I have to run (build) it on my device or publish it. This is the proper way right ?

Comment: You can run your app from Unity, just google how to

Comment: Google: Yes I did it the right way. Thanks for your helpfull answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The great Appodeal support helped me with this solution:

I had to embed the required frameworks (under Pods -> Products) in my target (Target -> BuildPhases -> Embed Frameworks).

[image]